# How do I do "cat f1 f2 >! f3" using "system"?

Tags: perl, shell

I tried all of the following with no luck:

```
system "cat f1 f2 >! f3";
system 'cat f1 f2 >! f3';
system "cat f1 f2 \>\! f3";
`cat f1 f2 >! f3`;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Because >! is a shell command, why not do the copy within perl?

Comment: What is that supposed to do?

Comment: @user1937198: What do you expect as the parameter to `system` if not a shell command?

Comment: @Borodin If you call `system` with multiple arguments or with a single string that doesn't contain shell meta-characters, it won't invoke the shell. So a possible answer would be: A program name (with arguments (maybe)). :-)

Comment: @melpomene: I'm aware of that, but in the context that **user1937198** is saying that the OP's calls don't work *"Because >! is a shell command"*, I'm wondering what *they think* is acceptable as a parameter to `system` if not a shell command. I would be surprised if they imagine that *only* multiple arguments or a program path is valid.

Comment: @Borodin True. That is a weird comment.

Comment: @melpomene, So what? Perl is simply emulating the shell as an optimization then. A bourne shell command is still required. (And you're not quite right either. The shell is bypassed even when spaces or `2>&1` are used despite being meta characters.)

Comment: @ikegami Oh, nice. I didn't know that about `2>&1`.

Comment: @melpomene, `perl -E'say $$; system("ps -o comm,pid,ppid 2>&1")'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That appears to be a `csh` command, so you will need to use `csh`.

```
system('/bin/csh', '-c', 'cat f1 f2 >! f3');
```

That said, `csh` is a pretty bad shell. You should consider switching to the bourne shell (especially for scripting).

```
system('/bin/sh', '-c', 'cat f1 f2 > f3');
```

The above can be shortened to the following:

```
system('cat f1 f2 > f3');
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for:system('/bin/csh', '-c', 'cat f1 f2 >! f3');

Comment: Yes, but I don't think that's what you should be using.

Answer (score 2):

The `>!` redirection operator is not standard. It may not exist in the `/bin/sh` that perl uses to run your commands. `>|` is more widespread. And since the purpose of `>!` or `>|` is to override the noclobber setting, you shouldn't need to use it at all. You may like to use noclobber in your interactive shell, but in scripts it shouldn't be enabled and `>` should work the same as `>|`.

In any case, using `system` is not the most efficient way to do basic file manipulation tasks from perl.